Windows Update updates OpenSSH to 9.5. And that is not working
I tried to post a comment to a similar thread, but I didn't have enough points (not strange, since this is my first post). Although I hope someone can solve the problem, I report this mostly as an FYI.
After the October updates, my OpenSSH server stopped working. I was in a hurry so I followed the advise to do a reinstall. Then I had (and solved, thanks to this forum) the problem with access rights on de logs folder. After that everything was fine until ... the next monthly updates.
This time I took a more detailed look into it and discovered that the update really did some updating: 7.7 had been replaced by 9.5. I have never been able to get 9.5 working on Windows Server and as it turned, neither did Microsoft.
But now it gets serious. Removing the OpenSSH feature, rebooting, and then adding it again restores 7.7. This means that Windows Update, didn't update the installation source.
Although this saved the day for me this time, this is really bad. I hope this is not the case for all updates because that would mean that you can reintroduce insecure versions of components by removing and then adding them again.
If someone can tell me how to get 9.5 working, I could decide to install that, but still I would prefer is that MS maintains a working version for me saving me the problem of making sure it stays up-to-date.
Thanks, Jan

If you’re experiencing issues with OpenSSH on Windows Server after it was updated to version 9.5, here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve the problem. Many users have reported similar issues after the October update.
1. Downgrade to OpenSSH 7.7
Since you mentioned that reverting to OpenSSH 7.7 resolved the issue temporarily, you can remove the current OpenSSH 9.5 and reinstall version 7.7. Here’s a step-by-step guide:

Remove OpenSSH 9.5:

Go to Settings > Apps > Optional Features.
Scroll to OpenSSH Server, click Uninstall, and reboot the server.


Reinstall OpenSSH 7.7:

Once rebooted, go back to Optional Features and re-add OpenSSH Server. This should restore version 7.7 as you observed.



Note: While this is a temporary solution, be aware that the downgraded version (7.7) might lack recent security updates. This could be a concern if 7.7 has known vulnerabilities.
2. Try a Manual Installation of OpenSSH 9.5
If you still want to try OpenSSH 9.5, you could attempt a manual installation to see if it resolves compatibility issues. Here’s how:

Download OpenSSH 9.5: Download the latest compatible OpenSSH version from the official OpenSSH GitHub repository.
Install OpenSSH 9.5:

Unzip the downloaded file and copy its contents to C:\Program Files\OpenSSH.
Run the following PowerShell commands as Administrator to install the service:
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH"
.\install-sshd.ps1


Set Permissions: Ensure the logs and configuration folders have correct permissions to avoid access errors:
icacls "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\logs" /grant "NT SERVICE\sshd:(OI)(CI)(F)"


Start the OpenSSH service and test if it runs as expected.



3. Report Issue to Microsoft and Monitor Updates
If OpenSSH 9.5 remains problematic, consider reporting it to Microsoft directly, as they may release a fix or configuration update. Keep an eye on Windows Server updates for any patches related to OpenSSH.
4. Be Cautious with Future Updates
Be aware that removing and re-adding OpenSSH reverts to the older version, which might not be secure. If you decide to stay with 7.7, keep monitoring for updates to ensure the system remains secure. A long-term solution may require that Microsoft addresses this issue with OpenSSH 9.5 directly.

Hopefully, this helps manage the situation with OpenSSH until a more stable fix is available.
